# Angular 4 CI TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

i want to show the data to the form and

i have this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

heres my component :

```
  book:Book;
  getBook(){
    var id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.bookService.getBook(id)
    .subscribe(book=>{
     this.book = book;
    })
  }
```

and this is my view

```
<div class="card col-md-5">
<div class="card-body">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="Title" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p  class="form-control" disabled name="title" >{{book.title}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="Author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Author</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p  class="form-control"  name="title">{{book.author}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">ISBN</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <p  class="form-control" disabled name="title" >{{book.isbn}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button> -->
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [routerLink] ="['/book']" >CANCEL</button>                
            </div>

        </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

is there anything wrong on my view or just on my component

Comment: I'd guess that the book you're looking for hasn't been found, hence you getting an error when you try to examine its properties.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set a default value for this 'book' property

```
book:Book = new Book();
```

or use ngIf to ensure the 'book' exists

```
<div class="card-body" *ngIf="book">
```

Comment: why did you added an answer to a question that you marked yourself as dup?

Comment: Because I remember later that I have answered a similar question. Anyway, I don't think this current answer should be marked as "not useful" as long as it is right, even if duplicated.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844 ;)